# getting the length of an array of elements when the number can change (adding or removing elements)

Tags: javascript, html-lists

So I don't have code for the question but Im curious to know if i wanted to create a ul of li's and want to add and remove the li's, I know the number of li's will be dynamic. So how do I get the number of li's (array indexes) when its adding or removing. I have tried doing
const len = document.querySelectorAll("li") and this will only return the length of the array static, if I add or remove li's it wont change the length of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName("li")` returns a live HTMLCollection, so its length should always be up-to-date.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id li").length
```

will give you the count.

Comment: i think the problem with this is my list starts out with nothing so im getting a null error

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the parent element and checking the [childElementCount](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/childElementCount) property:

```js
const len = document.querySelector("ul").childElementCount;
```

Note that you have to do this every time you add or remove an `<li>`. The `len` variable will be the the number of element **at the time of execution of the code.**
This is also what's happening with your code, if you add/remove an `<li>` and then redo the code, the number will change:

```js
// Let's imagine you have 3 <li> inside a <ul>.
const len = document.querySelectorAll("li");
alert(len.length); // will print 3

// Creating the new <li> element..
const newLi = document.createElement("li");
newLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode("I am new!"));
// ..and adding it to the <ul>
document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(newLi);

// Can't use "len" again here since it's a constant
const len2 = document.querySelectorAll("li");
alert(len2.length); // will print 4
alert(len.length); // will still print 3
```

Comment: tried this no luck

Comment: @jch0411 Are you checking the same `len` variable after you add/remove a `<li>` element ? In any case I edited my answer and added an explanation about that.